# tidyverse: Simulating random sample with nested factor

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, simulation, tibble

I want to simulate random sample with nested factor. Factor `Dept` has two levels `A` & `B`. Level `A` has two nested levels `A1` and `A2`. Level `B` has three nested levels `B1`, `B2` and `B3`. Want to simulate random sample from `2022-01-01` to `2022-01-31` using some `R` code. Part of desired output is given below (from `2022-01-01` to `2022-01-02` only for reference).

```
library(tibble)

set.seed(12345)
df1 <-
  tibble(
    Date   = c(rep("2022-01-01", 5), rep("2022-01-02", 4), rep("2022-01-03", 4))
  , Dept   = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B")
  , Prog   = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "B3", "A1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "A1", "A2", "B2", "B3")
  , Amount = runif(n = 13, min = 50000, max = 100000) 
  )

df1
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#>    Date       Dept  Prog  Amount
#>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 2022-01-01 A     A1    86045.
#>  2 2022-01-01 A     A2    93789.
#>  3 2022-01-01 B     B1    88049.
#>  4 2022-01-01 B     B2    94306.
#>  5 2022-01-01 B     B3    72824.
#>  6 2022-01-02 A     A1    58319.
#>  7 2022-01-02 B     B1    66255.
#>  8 2022-01-02 B     B2    75461.
#>  9 2022-01-02 B     B3    86385.
#> 10 2022-01-03 A     A1    99487.
#> 11 2022-01-03 A     A2    51727.
#> 12 2022-01-03 B     B2    57619.
#> 13 2022-01-03 B     B3    86784.
```

Comment: Is the `df1` your expected output or input data

Comment: Similar to `df1` from `2022-01-01` to `2021-01-31`.

Comment: Do you need `crossing(Date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-31"), by = "1 day"), Dept = c("A", "B"), Prog = 1:2) %>% mutate(Prog = str_c(Dept, Prog), Amount = runif(n = n(), min = 50000, max = 100000) )`

Comment: @akrun: Your code produces the output very close to my desired output with two exceptions, **(1)** `B` has three nested levels and **(2)** some combinations may miss for some dates.

Comment: your second condition not clear.  how many minimum/maximum combinations should be present

Comment: The min/max sampling 'n' is not clear.  Otherwise `crossing(Date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-31"), by = "1 day"), Dept = c("A", "B"), Prog = 1:3) %>%mutate(Prog = str_c(Dept, Prog)) %>% filter(Prog != "A3") %>% group_by(Date, Dept) %>% slice_sample(n = 2) %>% mutate(Amount = runif(n = n(), min = 50000, max = 100000))`

Comment: In your example sample, you created the first date with 5 elements, second with 4 and third 4.  Can you tell me the logic for those numbers

Comment: Just **Random**. There is **NO Pattern**.

Comment: But, still there would be some logic for min/max for each Date right?

Comment: Your previous comment serves the purpose. Please change it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to sample randomly, create the expanded data with `crossing` and then `filter/slice` to return random rows for each 'date'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
crossing(Date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-31"), 
   by = "1 day"), Dept = c("A", "B"), Prog = 1:3) %>%
   mutate(Prog = str_c(Dept, Prog)) %>%
  filter(Prog != "A3") %>% 
  mutate(Amount = runif(n = n(), min = 50000, max = 100000)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  slice(seq_len(sample(row_number(), 1)))  %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 102 × 4
   Date       Dept  Prog  Amount
   <date>     <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01 A     A1    83964.
 2 2022-01-01 A     A2    93428.
 3 2022-01-01 B     B1    85187.
 4 2022-01-01 B     B2    79144.
 5 2022-01-01 B     B3    65784.
 6 2022-01-02 A     A1    86014.
 7 2022-01-03 A     A1    76060.
 8 2022-01-03 A     A2    56412.
 9 2022-01-03 B     B1    87365.
10 2022-01-03 B     B2    66169.
# … with 92 more rows
```